# Movement in 1D given potential and initial data

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy

I am reading David Tong's introductory mechanics [course](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/relativity/dynrel.pdf) and he says the following (pages 14-15): suppose you have 1D movement given by the potential $V(x)=m(x^3-3x)$. What can you say about the path of a particle that is initially stationary at $x_0$? He says that if $x_0=\pm 1$ then the particle will stay there for all time (because these are local extremum points). It is not clear to me why this is so for $x_0=-1$.

What I understand by initially stationary is $\dot{x}(0)=0$. If $x_0=1$, since it's a local minimum we know that locally $V(x)\ge V(x_0)$ and by conservation of energy you want $\dfrac{m\dot{x}^2}{2}+V(x)=V(x_0)$, so the only possibility for this to happen is $\dot{x}=0$ so the particle has to stay at $1$. I don't understand why that is also true for $x_0=-1$; at $x_0=-1$ you have a local maximum and the same consideration as above using conservation of energy yields nothing since $V$ might decrease while $\dfrac{m\dot{x}^2}{2}$ might increase. I would like to understand why the particle remains at $-1$.

To be more rigorous mathematically, we have the ODE
$$\ddot{x}+3(x^2-1)=0$$
with initial data $x(0)=-1, \dot{x}(0)=0$ and we need to prove $x\equiv -1$. Conservation of energy  (i.e. multiplying the above relation by $\dot{x}$ and integrating)  gives $\dfrac{\dot{x}^2}{2}+x^3-3x=2$, but I have no idea how this might imply $x\equiv -1$. I tried playing around with the relation but did not reach anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

In this example: about $x_0 = -1$

I concur: from a physics perspective that point is a point of unstable equilibrium. Another example of unstable equilibrium: a needle balanced vertically on its sharp point. In real world physics that needle will fall down sooner or later.

However, in this specific case David Tong isn't looking at it from a perspective of physical reality. Here David Tong is discussing purely the mathematical properties of that cubic function. Granted, David Tong is using physics language to express the mathematical properties. But if he would go out of his way to not use any physics expression the narrative would become quite convoluted.

Mathematically, when a point is placed at $x_0 = -1$
there is nothing to make it roll either to the left or the right.

(I'm using the verb 'rolling' here. That 's an everyday language word but of course here you must take that in a completely abstract *mathematical* sense.)

In this specific case David Tong is using that cubic function to illustrate general properties of potential energy functions.

Comment: I would like to see a rigorous proof of the fact that it has to stay at $x_0=-1$, i.e. a proof that the ODE has the unique solution $x\equiv -1$.